# How to send values from javascript to julia using WebIO?

Tags: javascript, julia

I'm struggling to understand how to use `WebIO`. From the documentation, this would be an example to send values to javascript:

```
using WebIO
s = Scope()
obs = Observable(s, "logme", "")
onjs(
    s, "logme",
    js"""
    function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
    }
    """
)
```

Now, in order to test this, I run it in the REPL followed by

```
using Mux
WebIO.webio_serve(
    page("/", req -> s)
)
```

then point my browser (Brave) to localhost:8000 and open the console (via developer tools). At this point, I expect that running `obs[] = "hi there"` in the REPL would make that message show up in the console. But nothing happens. Why is my understanding of the expected behavior wrong? What should I do to make the javascript console log a message that I write to an observable on the julia side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is an error in the documentation. The problem is that there are no listeners on the observable. I.e., `julia> obs` returns `Observable{String} with 0 listeners.` You can add a listener by `WebIO.ensure_sync(s, "logme")`, or you can write it like this:

```
using Mux, WebIO, JSExpr
s = Scope()
obs = Observable(s, "logme",  "")
onjs(obs,
     js"""
     function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
     }
     """
     )
webio_serve(page("/", req -> s), 8000)
obs[] = "22"
```

Then the web console prints out the value 22.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to make it easier for casual readers: the difference is that we are passing the observable `obs` to `onjs`, instead of the scope and the observable's name.

Comment: Just discovered: one can also write `s[:logme]` instead of `obs`, which might be useful if a reference to the observable is not readily available.

Comment: Yes, I could have made it more clear. The information about the scope is already in the observable and `onjs(obs, [...])` calls `onjs(s, "logme", [...])`, but it also calls the `ensure_sync` before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It will helps

WebIO.webio_serve(
page("/", req -> s)
)